# Can I format HTML or CSS is a way that makes it easy for users to copy a block of text on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a way to format a section of my page so users can easily copy a small block of text while on a mobile device.

Are there any classes in Bootstrap, some HTML, or a way to format my CSS to make this easier. I know browsers except IE don't like javascript copying text to the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is specific to HTML & CSS for mobile, here are some thoughts.

1. I find that having large hit areas available on the elements you want the user to interact can help to start with. E.g. paddings on `<p>`s for example. So when a user starts tap-holding to initiate text selection, it'll more likely fall on the hit area of the paragraph. (A nifty trick is replacing margins with paddings!)
2. Try to make sure your content that is selectable follow a natural content flow box model. No weird floats or absolutely positioned content or otherwise content that might confuse the selection widget. Make it as document-like as possible!
3. Read up on the ways that you can control selection, e.g. `user-select` CSS property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select
4. You might want to disable text selection on elements that don't make sense, to help make text selection cleaner on the parts that matter.
5. Large font sizes are obvious, but maybe not so obvious is very large line-heights is fantastic for making text-selection a little less awkward! It can improve readability greatly on the side as well, my favourite for body text is `line-height: 1.6;`.
6. If you use viewport meta tag, make sure they can zoom in to fill the text/paragraph edge-to-edge comfortably when they want to. This can help a lot to get up close, to do the text selection and get tactile with your content.

---

However, if you do want to try JS, then I would recommend clipboard.js: https://clipboardjs.com/

Think also about what your users want to copy ahead of time, you might be able to do some analytics and allow users to highlight common text. This is done on Medium by the way to lead as a good example.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely try https://clipboardjs.com/.

```
<!-- Target -->
<div id="bar">Mussum ipsum cacilds...</div>

<!-- Trigger -->
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#bar">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

and activate it using following javascript `new Clipboard('.btn')`

Look created sample https://jsfiddle.net/gevorgha/fbeof421/

**Note**

There are some compatibility issues with iOS devices that do not copy target on trigger action, but it selects target and allows user to copy it manually.

Comment: That works great for desktop, but clipboardjs doesn't support mobile

Comment: I think it depends how do you use it. Javascript is fully functional on mobile too and it is just a matter of showing trigger button on mobile devices.

Comment: clipbboard.js worked fine on Android for me. I don't have a iOS device on hand, but desktop Safari does prompt the user to press ⌘ + C after selecting the text. I think on iOS it selects the text and the copy action is available to tap as if you had selected the text yourself?

Comment: True, on iOS it selects text too and allows you to copy text, however it does not copy it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it so that when they click on the element, all the text is selected automatically, so all they had to do, assuming they're using a modern mobile device, is long-tap and press copy to clipboard.

```
document.getElementById("TextParent").onclick(function(){
    fnSelect("TextParent");
});
```

So your html would look something like the following:

```
<div id="TextParent">
  Click anywhere in this div to select this text!
</div>
```

Adding to this, Nexii Malthus has a good point in regards to the hit areas on mobile phones, so maybe try to add some extra padding to the div.